# Single Sign Out (SSO) not working in keycloak

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am using two of my angular web applications to Keycloak for the single sign on functionality.

The sign in process is working fine but when I logs out from the first application the second application session does not expire and it does not get log out.

[image: Adding the client config screenshots for both applications.]

Comment: Did you find a solution?